# How to ensure at any given instant, the task from any queue will be executing by only one celery worker

Tags: celery, job-scheduling, celery-task

Suppose I have 3 queues and 3 celery workers. I want to ensure at any given instant of time, there will be only one task from any queue executing by any worker. can we do this. is there any locking mechanism or some kind of settings to do this ?

Comment: What about just assigning the three workers to only read from one of the queues each?

Comment: yes, we can do that , but that will not scale well horizontally. Is there any other way of doing this.I was thinking to chain the jobs in the queue. But don't know how to do this ?

Comment: In that case this seems like your best bet: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

I'm afraid that having only one task from any queue executed won't scale very well no matter how you do it...

Comment: No, it's like this... one task from one queue must be executed one at a time. suppose we have 10 queues, and at any instant max 10 jobs will be executing . i mean 10 jobs from 10 queues correspondingly. No two jobs from same queue will execute at the same time. I am implementing this for crawling where the two urls from same domain are not crawled at same time. I hope u got it well now. could u suggest what should i do ?

Comment: But in that case you could just as well have one worker per queue and not face any additional scalability issues, right? If you have 1000 queues it will spawn 1000 workers working on one queue each and that would still be within specifications?

Comment: Ya correct. But let's say i have 1000 queues and 500 workers, so in this case the worker can pick jobs from 2 queues concurrently and scale well right.

Comment: I see. Then I don't have a better suggestion than to have the tasks in each queue of different types and use the technique in the link I posted previously. There might be a smarter solution though.